# Ionic - Http post Request Data save error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Iam trying to save the following data set to DB , through http post request. Once i tried to perform the operation iam receiving a 400 (Bad Request error). Seek your valuable support. Also i the server will only accept JSON Request as well.

**Post request attempt**

```
 const newheadersNew = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization': window.sessionStorage.getItem("auth")
      };


    this.tes = 'hello';


    let atmobj = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("atmdetail"));

    this.survey = {

      "machineScreenCondition": form.value["screen"],
      "machineKeyboardCondition": form.value["keyboard"] ,
      "machineFaciaCondition": form.value["facia"],
      "machineBodyCondition": form.value["body"],

      "cubicleFloorWallCondition": form.value["floor.wall.condition"],
      "cubicleParandDoors": form.value["par.doors.appearance"],
      "cubicleRoofCeiling": form.value["roof.ceiling"],
      "cubicalwlea": form.value["con.wleak"],
      "cubicleCleaness": form.value["cubicle.cleaness"],
      "cubicalDustbin": form.value["cubicle.dustbin"],

      "appWallBranding": form.value["app.branding"],
      "appNboard": form.value["con.nboard"],
      "appSignboard": form.value["con.sboard"],
      "appColorWashing": form.value["con.washing"],
      "appOutside": form.value["out.appear"],

      "systemups": form.value["sys.ups"],
      "sysPlights": form.value["system.power.light"],
      "sysSlights": form.value["sys.sign.lights"],
      "sysCam": form.value["system.cam"],
      "sysAc": form.value["system.ac"],

      "atmStatus": this.note2,
      "otherComments": form.value["other.comments"],
      "atmImage": this.img,
      // "inspectedDate": atmobj["inspecteddate"],
      "user": { "name": window.sessionStorage.getItem("firstname").trim() + ' ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem("lastname").trim(), "username": window.sessionStorage.getItem("username") },
      "atm": { "id": atmobj["atmid"], "location": atmobj["atmname"], "city": atmobj["atmcity"] },
      "gpslocation": atmobj["gpslocation"]


    };

     console.log(this.survey);





     this.nativeHttp.post('https://'+window.sessionStorage.getItem('ip')+'/api/survey/submit', this.survey, newheadersNew)
      .then(
        data => {

          console.log(data);

        },
        error => {

          console.error(error);

        });
```

**Error - in console**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Ionic's proxies have quite different structure than Angular proxies - they are much simpler. An example would look like this:

*proxy.config.json*

```
{
  "/api/endpoint/*": {
    "target": "https://path.to.server.com",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api/endpoint/": ""
    }
  }
}
```

*ionic.config.json*

```
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "url": "/api/endpoint/*",
      "proxyUrl": "https://path.to.server.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since you will end up with pretty much the same data, I build the Ionic config automatically using simple Node script which 1) reads original Ionic config 2) reads Angular proxy.config.json 3) Inserts proxies into Ionic config and saves it. Such script could look like this:

```
const { readFileSync, writeFile } = require('fs');

try {
  /** Load configs */
  const proxyConfig = readFileSync('proxy.config.json');
  const ionicConfig = readFileSync('ionic.config.json');
  /** Format values */
  const proxyConfigFormatted = JSON.parse(proxyConfig.toString('utf8'));
  let ionicConfigFormatted = JSON.parse(ionicConfig.toString('utf8'));
  /** Start generating proxies */
  ionicConfigFormatted.proxies = Object.keys(proxyConfigFormatted).map((proxy) => {
    return {
      url: proxy,
      proxyUrl: proxyConfigFormatted[proxy].target
    };
  });
  /** Write new config */
  writeFile('ionic.config.json', JSON.stringify(ionicConfigFormatted, null, 2), (err) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    };
  })
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

**Edit:**
What HTTP client are you using?

**Original answer**:
Please provide us with some more details - the response you get from the request. It seems you are using Chrome - follow these steps and let us know the details:

1. Send the request
2. In DevTools, go to Network and find the request
3. Click on the request and then on the 'Response' tab to get the response from the server.

Otherwise, it's quite hard to say

Comment: Thank you for your comment
Response when inspected from network tab ->Error 400 Bad Request..

HTTP Client import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

I cannot use -import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
Due to CORS Error coming from server side..

Comment: But the response still needs to return some body describing the issue. I take it you do not have access to the server and can't view the log?

You can use Angular's HttpClient in Ionic app without the CORS issue if you use proxy. The thing is you need to specify proxy config in both Angular proxy.config.json, and in ionic.config.json.

Comment: Before implementing native http client, i tried with  Angular's HttpClient with proxy config , where i failed to perform an api request. Can you share me a quick guide how to perform the API Request perfectly with proxy config (I need to perform this operation in my Android device as well)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error related to [X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection)

`X-XSS-Protection` header stops pages from loading when they detect reflected cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Your server is configured to return:

- `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block` (do not render the document if XSS is found)

My suggestion is to check if your code is working against other APIs and will help you find the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. Also i noticed that when i tried with  Angular's HttpClient (Which i removed previously due to cors errors) working fine in google chrome (Web security disabled).  Any idea why ..

Comment: You need to check 2 things: 1. How do you require/import the ionic http client. 2. which server are you using? and I guess that you are setting X-XSS-Protection which started to be deprecated and you need to start using CSP.